# How would one go about designing a carrier sailing ship for flying mounts?

Tags: flight, ships, shipbuilding

Specifically, I am looking for a good design for a sailing ship with circa 17th century Earth technology that can carry a large swath of flying animals ridden by very small humanoids. The animals themselves have similar body structures to [Hatzegopteryx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatzegopteryx) from the late cretaceous, and there are specialized saddles for the small humanoids to ride them into battle. Additionally, the animals have been bred for thousands of years to be able to support saddles and riders. Since technology is roughly at a 1600s level, they are used in warfare as scouts and possibly to drop grenades on enemy ships and fortifications, although the last part is very tricky considering the difficulty of lighting a fuse under the wind conditions of flight. I could also take suggestions on how the creatures' presence in civilian and military settings would change early modern civilization and warfare, as well as different battle tactics that could incorporate them. TL;DR: what would be the design considerations for an age of sail "aircraft carrier" for flying creatures ridden by small humanoids?

Comment: How many of these creatures are going to be on each ship?

Comment: Naomi Novik's Temeraire series had dragons on ships. Napoleonic war technology. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temeraire_(series) Don't recall how much detail there was on ship design.

Comment: Are they carnivores or herbivores?

Comment: The ships of Zeng He, 15th century Chinese explorer, were upwards of 122m or 400 feet long. The first aircraft carriers were only about 140m long. So the ships of the Zeng He armada were certainly big enough. Now, use flying animals that take off from the water, like swans, and you have your waterborne air fleet. The first aircraft carriers use seaplanes that were lowered into the water.

Comment: Re lighting a fuse for grenades - there's a thing named [Bickford fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_fuse) that is capable to be invented in your world, since you've got grenades and thus gunpowder available. Use grenades with this and a jar with coal similar to a thurible for handy safe-ish ignition device, and there you go a flying bomber protected from wind.

Comment: Your biggest problem, methinks, could be food and water. Now, if they ate fish and could source their own food...

Answer (score 5):

A modern aircraft carrier has three distinguishing characteristics in its design. These are a flight deck, a hangar and it’s immense size.

**Flight Deck**

The majority of planes launched from carriers have historically required a considerable runway length to land and take off safely. Innovations in Vertical Take Off and Landing (VTOL) can alleviate some of this requirement, and your flying mounts might be similar to VTOL aircraft depending in this regard. If the creatures require a running start a flight deck analogue would be critical.

**Hangar**

Carriers need a place to store and and perform maintenance on the attached air craft. This is accomplished with a hangar deck below the main flight deck (modern American carriers use an elevator system to move the aircraft between decks). Your flying creatures would need a deck to shelter them from the elements while they slept and where they could be fed and otherwise attended to.

**Size**

Aircraft carriers in real life are staggeringly massive. They often have 5,000 people working aboard and the largest are over 1,000 feet long (300 meters for non Americans)  . No wooden ship could ever be as massive as a modern carrier, but given that flying creatures would likely be VTOL or at the very least require a much smaller landing strip you could have something perhaps a fifth of the size which is within the  engineering capabilities of the 17th century shipwrights.

Your ship should be multi decked with a more open top deck. The cargo capacity should be relatively high to provide food for the mounts and riders. Something like a carrack would provide enough decks, but a bomb ketch would provide a better top deck and high cargo capacity. If a large top deck is absolutely critical consider a galliot.

Comment: Air craft carriers are NOT massive. Many container ships, cruise ships, and tankers are much, much bigger.

Comment: For an idea of how big wooden sailing ships could be, see the general Zheng He exploration fleet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zheng_He The exact size is under dispute but either way there were much bigger than say Christopher Columbus ships.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Having seen an aircraft carrier before, I stand by my statement that they’re absolutely massive.

Comment: @
quarague
  They were almost as big as the first aircraft carriers

Answer (score 4):

**A sailing ship has lots of space for light flying animals to perch.**

[image: sailing ship]

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barque#/media/File:USRC_Salmon_P_Chase_-_LoC_4a25817u.jpg)

Your animals will ride on the masts.

[image: pigeons in a row]

[source](https://www.universityofcalifornia.edu/news/just-pigeons-people-tend-flock)

Maybe the crosspieces of the masts will be sturdier than would be the case if they just supported a sail.  The animals will just perch and ride around.  Riders can climb up the rigging to get on or the animals can fly down to get them.

Answer (score 3):

## The Turtle Ship:

A ship designed to launch flying creatures will need to be large, stable, and have open space on the decks. Since wind assists in the takeoff of aircraft (and your creatures will likely benefit from the same), a maneuverable ship would be good. The nature of ship battles will likely be heavily influenced by the ability to drop bombs and incendiaries (or potentially grapples and troops) from the sky. Armored decks will probably be critical to the designs.

A Geobukseon ([or turtle ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_ship)) was a Korean warship that first saw service in the 15th century, but was in use until the 19th. It has been described as the first armored ship. The upper deck was fully enclosed to protect from missiles raining down from above (including incendiaries). The sail arrangement is simpler than on European vessels, so there is less rigging to potentially get in the way of launching and landing flying creatures. They were big, fat, not terribly fast but very maneuverable vessels. They were sturdy enough to be usable to ram other ships.

[image: Scaled model of a turtle ship]

They are oared, so they can still maneuver if you should need to un-step the mast to expand deck area for flight operations. If you removed the defensive spikes from the top and included some openable hatches, this vessel could be quite functional as a flying creature carrier. Keep the spikes, and the same design is very defensible against the attacks of flying creatures (and the troops/grapples they might potentially land on your decks).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the mechanics of takeoff are still under debate, possibly including a lengthy [takeoff run](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/PTEROSAUR-TAKEOFF-GROUND-RUN-TIMES-AND-DISTANCES_tbl6_280299600). If the worst case estimates from the paper I googled were to apply, you would be lost for any realistic sailing ship.

A historical aircraft carrier would turn into the wind and accelerate to close to top speed to launch and recover heavily loaded aircraft. So one key design characteristic for your ship are high speed and being able to sail close to the wind. This tends to be problematic for square-rigged ships, which would otherwise be optimal for big, ocean-going craft. So possibly a [lateen rig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateen#Comparison_to_square_rig) in something like a large [dhow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baghlah)?

It would have to be even larger than historical examples, which might run into problems with the spars for lateen rigs.